# Android11: permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION prevents asking permissions

Tags: android, permissions, location

My app (taggeting API30) needs to collect fine location while in background.
It actually needs:

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
RECORD_AUDIO
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION (API >= 29)
```

So I set the following method:

```
public void checkMMPerms() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int extraperm = 0;
        String[] perms = new String[(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) ? 4 : 3];
        perms[0] = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        perms[1] = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
        perms[2] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            perms[3] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
            extraperm = checkSelfPermission(perms[3]);
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(perms[0]) + checkSelfPermission(perms[1])
            + checkSelfPermission(perms[2]) + extraperm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                 requestPermissions(perms, 0);
        else {
            RECPerms = true;
            GPSPerms = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method is that the `requestPermissions` returns Deny even if the user did not deny the permissions.

If I remove the `perms[3]` line, that is, not to ask for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` it works fine: it asks for the 3 permissions, but the location is set to "Allow only when using the app", as expected.

Why none of the permissions is asked if I add the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` perm?

**EDIT:** If I do not ask for `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in Android 11, the problem persists. So this does not work either:

```
public void checkMMPerms() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        String[] perms = new String[3];
        perms[0] = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        perms[1] = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
        perms[2] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            perms[2] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(perms[0]) + checkSelfPermission(perms[1])
            + checkSelfPermission(perms[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                 requestPermissions(perms, 0);
        else {
            RECPerms = true;
            GPSPerms = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot ask for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` simultaneously on android 11.

Comment: But if I simply do not ask for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, the problem is the same. It's like `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` prevents all the other ones from being called. Strangely, asking for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`  force the others to be denied.

Comment: Right, this is done intentionally. Here is a good article with some code snippets for different android versions: https://medium.com/swlh/request-location-permission-correctly-in-android-11-61afe95a11ad

Comment: Even when `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is activated and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is not, `requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, int)` not always opens any permission popup.